# How to remove virtual keypad from games/ apps

Tags: mobile, touch, 2d-games, keypad, addremoveprograms

I have an galaxy smart s6830 touch Chinese Mobile (240x320) (myriad java platform) (esmertec jbed) and I need to remove keypad from apps . I have put the following into the jar file but, unfortunately, it doesn't work:

```
LGE-MIDlet-Height: 400
LGE-MIDlet-On-Screen-Keypad: no
LGE-MIDlet-Width:240 
Navi-Key-Hidden: true
Nokia-MIDlet-On-Screen-Keypad: no
LGE-MIDlet-Display-Mode: both
LGE-MIDlet-Height: 480
LGE-MIDlet-Indicator: HIDE
LGE-MIDlet-On-Screen-Keypad: no
LGE-MIDlet-TargetLCD-Height: 320
LGE-MIDlet-TargetLCD-Width: 480
LGE-MIDlet-Width: 320
MIDlet-Landscape-Support: trueMIDlet-ScreenMode: ROTATE
MIDlet-Touch-Support: true
Navi-Key-Hidden: true
Nokia-MIDlet-No-Exit: true
ReverseSoftkeys: 
hideUseNativeCommands:
hideUseNativeTextButtons: hide
ATT-MIDlet-VirtualKeypad-Use: No
```

Please help me solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: No one here knows the solution?

Answer (score 0):

LGE-Midlet-Height: you used it 2 time in upper codepage